# How to automatically override the view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have an MVC site and I am now adding mobile views to it, optimized with jquery mobile.
All the controllers and models will stay the same.

So lets say you have a typical controller that returns a view:

```
    public virtual ActionResult CustomerProfile()
    {                
       return View(CurrentCustomer);
    }
```

I want something to check to see whether a session variable is set that says *IsMobileView == true*, and if so, I want it to return the same view name... EXCEPT with the suffix "_Mobile" in the aspx filename.

So in the above case, lets say we decorate the method with the attibute [SupportsMobile], if the session variable is set it will use "CustomerProfile_Mobile.aspx" as the view. If it doesnt [SupportsMobile] or the session isn't set to be in mobile mode, it should just return CustomerProfile.aspx as normal.

This needs to work with the syntax **return View("CustomerSearch", model)** also, which would return CustomerSearch_Mobile.aspx if the conditions were right.

How do I go about putting this check in? I can obviously override various action events in the controller, but I need to intercept where the view is being loaded up.

Thanks in advance! James.

Comment: I believe you get it out of the box, just add a `.mobile` or something like it, google  bit.

Comment: Found it for you, look for the section: `Overriding Views, Layouts, and Partial Views` [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)

Comment: Yes, no need to reinvent the wheel.Here's `Scott Hanselman`'s blog:[Making a switchable Desktop and Mobile site with ASP.NET MVC 4 and jQuery Mobile](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Scotts blog was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use **Session** for this. You should use `DisplayModeProvider` or other modern api's like `51Degrees` for this purpose. There's a lot of information from the **ASP.NET Team**

[Mobile Apps & Sites with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mobile)

Take a look and fallow the Architectural option that fits for your demand!